# Creating Imagebutton programmatically

Tags: android, click, imagebutton

I want to create several ImageButtons programmatically. I am able to create them but the click event listener keeps receiving the same view (Button 2), whether I click on button 0 ,button1 or button 2.

```
    RelativeLayout gameBoard = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelGameboard);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT,1);

    for(int i = 0 ; i <  3 ; i++)
    {

        ImageButton btnGreen = new ImageButton(this);
        btnGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_verde);
        btnGreen.setLayoutParams(lp);
        btnGreen.setOnClickListener(mGreenBallOnClickListener);
        btnGreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
        btnGreen.setTag(i);
        btnGreen.setId(i);

                    gameBoard.addView(btnGreen);


     }'
```

Click event listener:

```
private View.OnClickListener mGreenBallOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //check which green ball was clicked
        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) v;

    Log.i("greeny","Clicked on green ball->"+imgBtn.getTag()+" v.ID->"+v.getId());
    }
};
```

For any imagebutton drawn, when I click I get :  Clicked on green ball->2 v.ID->2

The buttons are in different positions ( i set a different padding for each one of them but in order to simplify the code I didn't put it here )

Answer (score 11):

Try adding a `onClickListener` -

```
private View.OnClickListener ClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int selected_item = (Integer) v.getTag();
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

Try creating a array of **`ImageButtons`** -

```
ImageButton[] btnGreen = new ImageButton[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    btnGreen[i] = new ImageButton(this);
    btnGreen[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_verde);
    btnGreen[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
    btnGreen[i].setOnClickListener(ClickListener);
    btnGreen[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    btnGreen[i].setTag(i);
    btnGreen[i].setId(i);

    gameBoard.addView(btnGreen[i]);
}
```

Comment: erm.. I already do that.. I keep getting the same tag thats the problem. I receive the same button in that parameter "View v"

Comment: that will crash. you don't even initialize each ImageButton object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
RelativeLayout gameBoard = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelGameboard);

ImageButton[] imageButtons;

private final int NUMBER_OF_IMAGE_BUTTONS = 5; //your number of image buttons

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT,1);

imageButtons = new ImageButton[NUMBER_OF_IMAGE_BUTTONS];

for(int i = 0 ; i < NUMBER_OF_IMAGE_BUTTONS; i++){
   imageButtons[i] = new ImageButton(this);
   imageButtons[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_verde);
   imageButtons[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
   imageButtons[i].setOnClickListener(mGreenBallOnClickListener);
   imageButtons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
   imageButtons[i].setTag(i);
   imageButtons[i].setId(i);
   gameBoard.addView(imageButtons[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you do not set layout of button, All button in same place.

```
Use Aboveof,Belowof,left,right,center
```

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477164/position-view-in-relativelayout-runtime)

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_ABOVE);  
    relativeLayout.addView(button, params);
```

Comment: Sorry I simplified the code and hide the paddings that I set after that definition. The buttons are in different places.